# What is the efficient way to replace Spark Dataset column value from a sortedMap using Scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `SortedMap` for example:

```
key   value
-----------
aaa     1
bbb     2
ccc     3
```

And Dataset with 3 columns:

```
col1   col2   col3
------------------
zzz     aaa     w
xxx     ccc     n
sss     bbb     v
```

I want to change the value of column `col2` from the `SortedMap`, so the resulting dataset would be the following:

```
col1   col2   col3
------------------
zzz      1      w
xxx      3      n
sss      2      v
```

I created an UDF

```scala
val udf1 = udf((col: String) => sortedMap(col).toString())
```

And wrote the following to change the column value

```scala
dataset.withColumn("col2", udf1($"col2"))
```

But the code is not working.

Comment: Not working how? Wrong answer or It gives an error? If it's the latter,  it would be helpful if you posted the error.

Comment: The program got stuck, no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *don't need to create `udf` function* for that. Simple `left join` and `select` function should do the trick

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dataSet.join(sortedMap, dataSet("col2") === sortedMap("key"), "left")
  .select(col("col1"), col("value").as("col2"), col("col3"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|zzz |1   |w   |
|xxx |3   |n   |
|sss |2   |v   |
+----+----+----+
```

**if your sortedMap dataset is small you can use broadcast**

```
val broadCasted = sc.broadcast(sortedMap)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dataSet.join(broadCasted.value, dataSet("col2") === broadCasted.value("key"), "left")
  .select(col("col1"), col("value").as("col2"), col("col3"))
  .show(false)
```